# Переменные вместо полей в ORM и PHP

Tags: php, orm

Использую PHPExcel.Процесс создания файла надо унифицировать-сейчас для формирования каждого файла своя функция(т.к. количество столбцов разное).
Есть выборка ORM и массив с переменными заголовков (каждая запись в массиве имеет такой вид ('name','имя')-то есть название поля в выборке и названия для вывода)
при обращении к полю в выборке делаю так

```
$item->($array_title[1][0]);
```

изначально так было

```
$item->name;
```

Конечно же ругается.

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' "

Конечно понимаю,что наивно,но вдруг бы прокатило)))
Так собственно,как можно извернуться и вместо 'name' вставить переменную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было еще чуть-чуть подумать и написать:

```
$item->{$array_title[1][0]};
```

Comment: Попробую завтра)

Comment: Работает! Спасибо=)